# Scripts folder a vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, security

In my .NET web applications I usually have a Scripts folder that contains all of my JavaScript files - jQuery mostly these days, with the occasional JavaScript library of some sort or another.

I'm running vulnerability scans against one of my websites through a scanner called Nexpose, and it informed me that the Scripts folder is open to the world - meaning unauthenticated users can download the JavaScript files contained in the folder and that this is a critical vulnerability. According to Nexpose, the Scripts folder should be restricted to only allow authenticated users to access it. Which leads me to my first question.

**How do I restrict the Scripts folder to only authenticated users?** I tried placing a web.config file into the Scripts folder and denying access to all unauthenticated users that way, but it didn't work. I was able to determine this myself but going to my website's login page, but not logging in, and then typing https://mywebsite/scripts/menubar.js and sure enough it allowed me to download the menubar.js file.

Second question - **Why is this considered a vulnerability?** I've tried to reason my way through the possibilities here, but I've failed to come up with much at all. Is it a vulnerability simply because Joe the l33t h4x0r could figure out the various libraries that I'm using and then maybe use known exploits against them?

**Update**

Overwhelmingly the answer seems to be that in no way should a vulnerability exist just because a .js file can be opened and read on the client's browser. The only vulnerability that might exist would be if the developer were using the .js file in an insecure fashion of some sort (which I'm not).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logically, you wouldn't want to actually disallow access to the actual files because then you couldn't use them in your webpage. The webserver makes no distinction between a browser requesting a file as part of the process of rendering a webpage versus someone just manually downloading the file.

As a result, the answer to your first question is: you can't and wouldn't want to. If you don't want users to access take it out of the web folder. If it's required to render your site, then you *want* anyone to have access to it so your site can render properly.

As to why it's considered a vulnerabiliy, who's saying it is? I can go pull any JavaScript Facebook uses right now. Or, more to the point, I could go to Bank of America or Chase's website and start looking through their JavaScript. If I had an account, I could even take a look at the JavaScript used once the user is logged in.

The only thing that you might need to worry about is the same thing you always need to worry about: exposing details that shouldn't be exposed. I'm not sure why you would, but it obviously wouldn't be a good idea to put your database password in a JavaScript file, for example. Other than things like that, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Agreed.  *Nexpose* is hardly the final authority on such matters.

Comment: That isn't necessarily true, the last piece about nothing to worry about. If your webserver has write access to the directory and I make it write Woot4Moo's custom Javascript file no one is going to be happy, or more importantly any file that I can trick the server into writing.

Comment: Therein lies the problem - Nexpose is telling me it is a vulnerability. One would think that a vulnerability scanning tool would know if something truly were a vulnerability or not. However I realized that this might not be the case (meaning that it might not be a vulnerability) and figured I'd do good posting on stackoverflow about it.

Comment: What you're saying shouldn't be discounted, so don't get me wrong, but you'd actually have to *work* to make your server that insecure. Every file is going to default to write privileges only for the creator, and the webserver is always going to default to having it's own segregated user and group. You'd have to give global write privileges, run the server as an admin/root, and disable multiple other security measures before you could actually pull off such a vulnerability. While you are correct, I'm not going to lose sleep over it tonight.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - If the Scripts folder has write access to everyone then I have a big, big problem indeed. But it doesn't... or it shouldn't. That just gives me the shivers even thinking about.

Comment: @Jagd correct if world access exists never good.  My statement was if the webserver has write access to it.  Often times write access is given even though it shouldnt be.

Comment: @Woot4Moo - Ok, I think we're on the same page now. The webserver doesn't have write permissions to Scripts folder... or it shouldn't anyway. If it does then heads are going to roll! Thanks for your ideas and help on this.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases it's not a vulnerability. Consider all of the massive public sites with anonymous traffic and/or where it's very easy to become an authenticated user (Google, eBay, Amazon, etc.) These sites also have some of the most elaborate scripts.

The more subtle thing to watch out for are other files which you DO want protected. For example, if users must login to your site and purchase a document, video, image, etc. before viewing it, it certainly should not be in a publicly accessible folder.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Nope, I don't have anything like that going on here. Its just a folder that contains .js files; however, you've given me something new to think about here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should keep most of your processing to be done server-side, as most (if not all) client-side scripts can be edited, and such. Most sites use Javascript, so simply using it isn't dangerous, you just have to be careful about what you do with it.

Also, to answer your first question, don't protect them if unauthenticated users need them too.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some security suite has an itchy trigger finger.  The only two problems I could see is that you could end up loaning your server out as a CDN if someone chooses to point to *your* jQuery or *your* -insert library name here- OR (now this is a real security risk) if you are also serving any kind of dynamic .js files out of there that could pose a potential threat.  The only other thing I can think of is if you have your "custom" app js in the mix with all the libraries someone could potentially discover your endpoints (web services and such) and try and see if they're secure... **but that's it!** nothing more... (unless you did something really dumb like hard code a password or something in there... lol)

Answer (score 1):

So the attack isn't that people can edit the script the attack is getting the web server to arbitrarily write to a directory.  What you need to do is make sure they are read-only files.  chmod 400 or windows read.  In terms of Defense in Depth (DiD) you want to make sure the web server is a non-privileged user that cannot log into the system.  Further what needs to occur is that you are doing all data sanitization on the server, irrespective of what you are doing on client side, because you do not control the client side.  Typically this involves making sure that you cleanse all data coming from the web as well as the database before it gets served.  One of my favorite things to do is insert arbitrary javascript into the database and watch it do things in the UI because the development team assumed everything would be fine since they already cleaned it once.

I can provide more details around securing the system if it is warranted.